# Spectral decomposition on GL(n)

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

If $\Delta_1, \ldots, \Delta_{n-1}$ are a basis of the ring of commuting bi-$SL(n,R)$-invariant differential operators, $L_0^2=L_0^2(SL(n,Z)\backslash SL(n,R))$ is the space of cuspidal automorphic functions on $SL(n,R)$, and $\tau$ is some non-trivial irreducible representation of $SO(n,R)$, let $L^2_0(\tau)$ be the subspace of functions $f$ such that $f(gk)$ lies in the span of the matrix coefficients of $\tau$ as a function of $k\in SO(n,R)$, for each fixed $g\in SL(n,R)$.

Then $L^2_0(\tau)$ can be decomposed into a Hilbert-space direct sum of simultaneous eigenspaces of all of the $\Delta_i$. One way to show this is to apply the same decomposition to $L^2_0$ as a whole, and then get back to $L^2_0(\tau)$ by integrating against the matrix coefficients.
First question:  Who first showed this (reference?), and is there a direct argument (not using the words "right regular representation")?

If $B$ is the group of upper triangular matrices, and $\chi$ is a character of $V$, the group of diagonal matrices with $\pm 1$'s on the diagonal (the "boundary" of $SO(n,R)$), we can further decompose to $L^2_0(\tau,\chi)$, the space of functions $f$ satisfying $f(bvk)=\chi(v) f(bk)$ for $b\in B$, $v\in V$, $k\in SO(n,R)$.
Second question:  Do we still have the spectral decomposition of this smaller space? (Reference?)

EDIT: Left invariance by $V$ implies some parity relations for the Fourier-Whittaker coefficients, so in fact everything in $L^2_0(\tau)$ which is an eigenfunction of the $\Delta_i$'s is already in one of the $L^2_0(\tau,\chi)$; this answers the second question in the affirmative.